# "Have a shower" vs "Take a shower"

Tags: grammar

According to [take-a-shower-bath-or-have-a-shower-bath](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/take-a-shower-bath-or-have-a-shower-bath.547849/), there are already many answers there, but it's still not clear for me.

I still wonder that

`Have a shower` and `Take a shower`, are they the same or not?

Which one to use?

To use `Have a shower` or `Take a shower`, it's dependent on context? or maybe is dependent on English dialect?

Comment: Take a shower is an Americanism whereas have a shower is British English

Comment: In imperative speech, to my BrE ears "take" not "have" would sound  grating and very slightly assertive.

Answer (score 2):

According to Oald it is "to have a shower/to take a shower" in BrE. "to take a shower" is especially used in AmE.

http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/shower_1?q=shower

Comment: But yes, they mean the same thing.